# AngularJs - Dynamic template

Tags: angularjs, templates, dynamic, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement directive for dynamic template. Depending on what is selected in drop-down list, template should change. I only manage so far to implement to be dynamic on page load, but when value in drop-down list is changed, template stays the same..`(function () {
    'use strict';

```
// directive for loading incomeinformation, regular or military
angular.module('myModule').directive('dynamicTemplate', templateControl);

templateControl.$inject = [];

function templateControl() {
    var directive = {
        controller: mycontroller,
        controllerAs: 'mycontrollerCtrl',
        bindToController: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<ng-include src="mycontrollerCtrl.getTemplateUrl()"/>'
    };

    return directive;

    function mycontroller($attrs, $element, $scope, $compile) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.getTemplateUrl = getTemplateUrl;           
        function getTemplateUrl() {
            if ($attrs.templateId == 1)
                return "test1.html";
            if ($attrs.templateId == 3)
                return "test1.htm2";

            return "test3.html";
        }
    }
}
```

})();`

And in html: `<dynamic-template templateid="{{model.TemplateId}}"></imp-dynamic-template>`

Comment: I think you might be taking a wrong approach (in angular terms) to solve the problem. Could you please describe business functionality that you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I have a product types, and based on which product is selected different template for edit needs to be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in html: attribute name must be "template-id" because you access it like $attrs.templateId